# Permissions using a TYPE as a Table Valued Parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm developing a .Net App that calls an stored procedure that have a table valued parameter declared as a TYPE READONLY.

First time I tried to call the SP I received the next error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
>   The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'TYPE_OBJ', database 'MY_DB', schema 'dbo'.

After granting EXECUTE permission to the user it works fine.

But I can't find in MS-DOCS neither in [CREATE TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) nor in [Use table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) any reference to the permissions needed to use it as a parameter.

Where can I find information about the necessary permissions to use a TYPE as a parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where can I find information about the necessary permissions to use a TYPE as a parameter?

I've submitted a PR against the doc page to get the requirements documented.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/3351

Here's a simple repro:

```
create type dbo.tt as table(id int)

go

create procedure dbo.ptt @tt tt readonly
as
select * from @tt

go

create user joe without login



grant references on type::dbo.tt to joe
grant execute on dbo.ptt to joe

go

execute as user='joe'

  declare @t tt
  exec ptt @t 
  --The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'tt', database 'a', schema 'dbo'.

revert

go

grant execute on type::dbo.tt to joe

go

execute as user='joe'

  declare @t tt
  exec ptt @t 
  --no error

revert
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to give permissions to the [REFERENCES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522526(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> The REFERENCES permission is required on the user-defined table type
>   when the table type is a parameter in a routine...

Comment: See repro above, where REFERENCES is insufficient.